# Curonian Spit and Kaliningrad

Tags: russia, lithuania, baltic-sea, kaliningrad, curonian-spit

The [Curonian Spit](http://whc.unesco.org/en/list/994) is one of the places I would like to visit. As an EU citizen, the obvious approach is to focus on the Lithuanian side.

Nevertheless, I wonder if it is worthwhile to pay a visit to the Russian side of the spit in particular and to Kaliningrad in general. Is it worth incurring the additional hassle, such as e.g. obtaining a Russian visa? If yes, how much time would you allow? Is it something that could be done on a day trip from Lithuania or is it better to spend a couple of days in the Kaliningrad oblast?

Comment: [Russia expert mode on] When will you travel?[Russia expert mode off]

Comment: Not yet decided: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3826/766

Comment: In 1994, I met two American foreign exchange students who were living in Kaliningrad, but who were taking a day trip to Gdansk (where I was also visiting).  Like you, I'm really interested in visiting the oblast - but they were telling me that its an industrial pit, with all of the interesting stuff having been blown up in WWII (Amber Room, anyone?).  I also remember it was a fairly expensive visa at the time...

Comment: @Affable Geek Amber Room was in Pavlovsk, near Saint-Petersburg, and never were in Kaliningrad. In 2003 [it had been reconstructed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amber_Room#Reconstructions)

Answer (score 11):

I think, the Curonian split is the same from both sides, Lithuanian and Russian side. So, if you are interested in only Split - you should not bother about visit the Kaliningrad. But:

As I've already said [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/3953/19), my mother is from Kaliningrad, and I've been there near half of my life, especially during summer holidays. I love this town, and my opinion is what you should visit it **near for week**. And what's why:

1. The symbol of the town is the [Königsberg_Cathedral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nigsberg_Cathedral):
   In 1982:
   [image]
   Nowadays:
   [Cathedral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsQmI.jpg)
   [image]
   It is reconstructed now (and some work is still being made, but economic crisis brought some problems for this process), it's works as catolic and orthodox church, and has two museums inside - the Kant's museum and Cathedral history museum.
   Also there is the Kant's Tomb:
   [image]
2. The fishers's district - this a small place near the Cathedral where you can get funny photoes, try some sea food and so on:
   [image]
   [Door to nothere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1BKc.jpg)
   [Romantic bench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwWPV.jpg)
   [Pirate with monkey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB2mZ.jpg)
   [Modern sculpture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbiCY.jpg)
   [Money bird](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRdGH.jpg)
3. [the Amber museum](http://ambermuseum.ru.swteh.ru/info/). Very beatiful, amazing work inside.
   [image]
4. City near Kaliningrad - [Svetlogorsk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svetlogorsk,_Kaliningrad_Oblast). Small beautyfull city with many great places to walk and huge amount for the buying something made in amber.
   [image]
5. If you are sea-interested person, or you are traveling with kids, you could be interested in visiting the Zoo
   [image] and Sea museum
   [image]
6. A lot of ships are available for visiting, such as
   Vityaz:
   [image: Vityaz]
   Submarine B-413:
   [image]
   Cosmic ship:
   [image]
7. Marine base in Baltiisk:
   [image]
8. Reconstructered [King's Gate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King%27s_Gate_%28Kaliningrad%29) (museum inside):
   [image]
9. Restaurants inside old forts all over the town (on photo - Wrangel's cafe):
   [image]
   [image]
10. [Fort Friedrich Wilhelm III](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82_%E2%84%96_5) - memorial of the Second World War - for the extreme trip. If you can, find locals to get inside the memorial. It is [awesome](http://www.google.ru/search?hl=ru&safe=off&biw=1269&bih=905&q=%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=124919l126220l0l126313l10l9l0l0l0l4l215l1357l2.4.3l9l0&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&authuser=0&ei=ScXhTsf8L8GG-wbwl92vBQ)!
    [image]
    [image]
11. And a lot lot more. You can even made a trip to the Gdansk - the buses are regular, 6 hours - and you are on place.

Some reports with more photoes (in Russian):

- [First](http://easyeurope.ru/kaliningrad-rossiya-i-evropa/)
- [Second](http://river-forum.ru/showthread.php/163-%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2-%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%9A%D0%92%D0%94-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82-%D1%85-%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80-%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2)
- [Third](http://tourbina.ru/common/photo/43823/palbum/36/)
- [Fourth](http://jst-ru.livejournal.com/156463.html)

Comment: You mention Baltijsk, but I'm quite sure that non-Russians are forbidden to visit. Is that no longer the case?

Comment: @MrMartin This city is no longer in "borders" zone, but one still need a permission to visit Baltijsk, which can be got (with some preparation and paperwork)

Answer (score 5):

VMAtm made a perfect answer about Kaliningrad, here are my two cents about Curonian Spit.

First of all, for me the Russia part and Lithuanian part do differ **a lot**. On the Russian part you could find:

- Ornitological station, where you could see how ornitologists catch birds during their season migrations and put rings on them (last years you need to book a tour to get into it, and season migrations are in spring and autumn, of course)
- 4-5 "eco-routes" that are very interesting to walk through. They are [listed on the russian Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%80%D1%88%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0#.D0.9F.D0.B5.D1.88.D0.B5.D1.85.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D1.82.D1.83.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.BC.D0.B0.D1.80.D1.88.D1.80.D1.83.D1.82.D1.8B_.D0.9D.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.BE.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.BE_.D0.BF.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.BA.D0.B0_.C2.AB.D0.9A.D1.83.D1.80.D1.88.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.B0.C2.BB) at but I hope you could translate it with [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com). See also: [Dancing Forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Forest).

Comment: We liked trails very much when we were there.