# Travel guide to Kaliningrad?

Tags: russia, guidebooks, kaliningrad

I'm looking for a travel guide (i.e. book) to Kaliningrad.  Are there any particularly useful English-language references for visitors to Kaliningrad?  I am particularly interested in any remnants of the old Königsberg.

Comment: See also: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3804/curonian-spit-and-kaliningrad

Answer (score 6):

Well there are lots of sites online that cover this.

For example you could look at [Wikitravel's page on Kaliningrad](http://wikitravel.org/en/Kaliningrad).

It looks like the top site from the old capital Königsberg is the cathedral, built in 1333.  There is an English-language page on [their official site](http://www.sobor-kaliningrad.ru/eng/).

[image]

Comment: Wikitravel's page is useful but a bit sparse.  I'd like something that does more than list the main sights.

Answer (score 5):

Königsberg was destroyed during WWII, and then reconstructed. So there are some old houses, but not as many as you can hope to find.

As Mark said, you should start with Cathedral, and Kant's Tomb.
After that you can continue with some forts inside and outside the city, and visit some small city in Kaliningrad region. Especially I recommend the [Svetlogorsk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svetlogorsk,_Kaliningrad_Oblast).

You can find much more information in [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/3954/19).

And about guidebooks - you can buy many of them inside the city - in bookstores or in travel agencies. A [virtual excursions on city](http://kenigmap.in-pic.com/) are available at [Friedland gate site](http://en.fvmuseum.ru/)

There are also good [online guide](http://www.konigsberg.ru/eng/).

Answer (score 4):

Although I still consult the default guides (e.g. lonely planet, rough guide), I find my self more and more to rely on online resources, specifically build around satnav devices.

My three favorites are 1. [Geocaching.com](http://www.geocaching.com), 2. [routeyou.com](http://www.routeyou.com), and 3. [Everytrail.com](http://www.everytrail.com).
Geocaching is nice, specifically if locals engage in this fun activity. Then again, you need to speak russian to appreciate the caches to the fullest.

So although these three online resources don't provide an extensive source on written descriptions, all provide interesting focal points in any destination, at least in my experience.

Routeyou has a very interesting route in [Kaliningrad](http://www.routeyou.com/en/route/view/72737/walking-and-hiking-route-seven-bridges-of-konigsberg-walk.en). In never realized that the in mathematical circles well known [Travelling sailes man problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) is actually based on [Kaliningrad](http://www.routeyou.com/en/route/view/72737/walking-and-hiking-route-seven-bridges-of-konigsberg-walk.en)
[image: Source: Wikipedia]
Source: Wikipedia.org

Comment: The bridges of Königsberg problem are not particularly related to traveling salesmen -- except that the problem is generally regarded as one of the earliest starts of graph theory.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a guide in the local tourist information center: http://www.visit-kaliningrad.ru/

And there are several books in Amazon about Kaliningrad in English: http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss/276-9024839-7416712?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=kaliningrad+guide